# ’Call to a member function make() on null‘ When installing Eloquence

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to install Eloquence on my Laravel project.

[Eloquence Installation](https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence/wiki/Installation)

I'm following the installation, and I've done the following:

1. Require the package in your composer.json
2. Add Eloquence trait to the model
3. Add Sofa\Eloquence\ServiceProvider to the config/app.php providers array

**Problem**: `Post::search('jarek sofa')->get();` results in

```
FatalThrowableError in Builder.php line 77:
Call to a member function make() on null
```

[Here is my code](http://hastebin.com/qogiwafaki.php)

**Possible reasons:**

1. The Eloquence service provider wasn't registered properly
2. Maybe something to do with composer

Thanks in advance

Comment: As per this issue on Github, https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence/issues/56, it sounds like your Service Provider wasn't registered properly. Ensure it is and you can try running `php artisan cache:clear` and `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Yeah I saw that issue too. I feel like it's because I didn't register the service provider properly, but from what I understand, registering a service provider is simply adding `Sofa\Eloquence\ServiceProvider::class` into the `providers` array in `config/app.php`, which I have done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it to work!

**Solution**: Add `\Sofa\Eloquence\Builder::setParserFactory(new \Sofa\Eloquence\Searchable\ParserFactory);`

in the `AppServiceProvider` boot method like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        \Sofa\Eloquence\Builder::setParserFactory(new \Sofa\Eloquence\Searchable\ParserFactory);
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: It works for me! Now I have a error when I setting $searchableColumns = ['my_custom_field'] on my model.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run composer update command in console?

Comment: I just ran `php artisan cache:clear`, `composer dump-autoload`, and `composer update` in the console. No change at all

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue resolved it as following
added dependencies to the composer
    "require": {
        "sofa/eloquence": "~5.3", // for Laravel 5.3.*

```
    // OR
    "sofa/eloquence": "~5.2", // for Laravel 5.2.*

    // OR
    "sofa/eloquence": "~5.1", // for Laravel 5.1.*

    // OR
    "sofa/eloquence": "~0.4", // for Laravel 5.0.*
    ...
},
```

then added the class in config/app
    'providers' => [

```
    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    .....
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */
    Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,

    Sofa\Eloquence\ServiceProvider::class,
],
```

finally did the composer update

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bump an old topic, but I have a different solution to anyone who might find themselves here: you cannot have a scope called 'search'.

I just had the exact same exception and couldn't work out why, although I figured it was a problem with me trying to call a scope dynamically through call_user_func_array. Thanks to this question having the exact same scope name, I figured it might be that and it was. There's probably many other 'reserved' names I don't know about, but as soon as I changed it to 'searchName' all is well.